# How to add default props to styled components in material-ui?

Tags: typescript, material-ui, styled-components

How do I set default props on custom styled components in MUI? Currently, I have to add `maxWidth="sm"` on each instance which I would rather have baked in.

```
const MyContainer = styled(Container)(({ theme }) => ({
  marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
}));

...

<MyContainer maxWidth="sm" /> // what I have

<MyContainer /> // what I want
```

Answer (score 0):

You can abstract away the functionality into an intermediary component.

```js
import Button, { ButtonProps } from "@mui/material/Button";
import styled from "@mui/material/styles/styled";

export type MyComponentProps = ButtonProps & {
  myNewVariable: string;
};

function MyComponentImpl(props: MyComponentProps) {
  return <Button variant="outlined" {...props} />;
}

export const MyComponent = styled(MyComponentImpl)(
  ({ myNewVariale, theme }) => ({
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "center",
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
  }),
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use attrs for styled component. In example below, using "sm" variant container as default.

Docs: https://styled-components.com/docs/api#attrs

```
const MyContainer = styled(Container).attrs((p) => ({
  maxWidth: p.maxWidth || "sm"
}))(({ theme }) => ({
  marginTop: theme.spacing(2)
}));

const App = () => <MyContainer>1</MyContainer>;
```

Comment: MUI uses `emotion` engine instead of `styled components`, so they don't have `attrs` prop function